# Using Bootstrap striped tables without adding class="table table-striped"

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap offers tables with striped rows: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#striped-rows.
You need to add a class to the HTML table element to use them.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
</table>
```

What if you can't change the HTML?  Only the css?
In other words: I'm stuck with a lot of existing HTML files with regular table element (no classes):

```
<table>
  ...
</table>
```

I do want these tables to have striped rows.

Can I use a CSS solution to apply the styles that are defined in Bootstrap's .table-striped to regular tables?

```
.table-striped {
  ...
}
```

Or do I have to overwrite Bootstrap, by creating my own CSS file?

Comment: Adding a class using javascript is trivial (and easy to research how)

Comment: Thank you.  I've never used javascript, but it was indeed trivial to add the needed class with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your css

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }
```

But (always is a but :) ) I don't suggest to do that.
Why? It is the way that BS4 do it. What if you install a new bootstrap version? This code matches with version 4.5 but it could not match with version 5. So you have to review it each time.

The right solution is to dive into SCSS. This working model has many advantages over common css. You can write BS4 or whatever you want, compile based on variables (for example you set a color and that color is replaced throughout the project), nest formats, and many more advantages.
It costs a bit at first, but once you get hold of it, it's like programming in php but in CSS.
I suggest reviews this [link](https://sass-lang.com/guide).

good luck